# Why can’t an elementary particle be forced to have a particular outcome in an entangled pair?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, quantum-states

I read in a blog [Quantum Entanglement: Slower Than Light](https://briankoberlein.com/blog/quantum-entanglement/) that one can not force a particle from an EPR pair to have a not statistical outcome for the entanglement parameter. I can not understand why? Is it prohibited by some no go theorem?

A sort of explanation is included in [Chad Orzel blog](https://www.forbes.com/sites/chadorzel/2016/05/04/the-real-reasons-quantum-entanglement-doesnt-allow-faster-than-light-communication/#945b6e73a1eb):

He writes there:

> If you could measure a particle's state in a way that forced a particular outcome-- you could absolutely send information this way. But you can't do that.

And then:

> If Alice does this on her particle, it does not, in fact, affect the state of Bob's particle in any way-- it's still in an indeterminate state that's a mix of 0 and 1.

All this is just a statement and not answer to why the particle can not be forced in a particular state by some process?

Comment: Could you summarise the procedure you think should work, and then people can explain why it doesn't. I don't want to trawl through blog posts.

Comment: @jacob1729 I think the procedure is obvious. A and B systems (elementary particles probably) are in an entangled state [1A>[0B>+[0A>[1B> and Alice forces A to give 1 on her wish by using some physical constrains on A (note that A is not measured!). Then B is 0. If she doesn't do that A is 50/50% --->1/0. Simple measurement on B reveals without classical channel what A has done.

Comment: The issue is 'forces A to give 1' is not simple and I'm not clear how you envisage this happening. I've written an answer that shows why the first way that occurred to me wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The proposed experiment is something like this: Alice and Bob prepare a system in the Bell state:

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle  + |10\rangle)$$

Alice then goes somewhere and wants to communicate say the value "1" to Bob faster than light. To do this, she acts with the operator $U \otimes \mathbf{1}$ on the state (this is a local operation so she can do this). $U$ is chosen such that if she were now to measure her qubit, she'd measure the value $0$.

So, first issue: such a unitary doesn't exist. This would need to map $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ to the same state $|0\rangle$ so is not reversible so can't be unitary*. Okay, this can be worked around by Alice bringing her qubit into contact with a second one (in the state $|0\rangle$ say) and then we can construct a system that maps $|00\rangle \mapsto |00\rangle$ and also $|10\rangle \mapsto |01\rangle$.

The issue is that none of this has actually affected Bob's qubit in any way. Sure, if Alice now measures her qubit then she will definitely record a $0$. But Bob is still 50% likely to measure either $0$ or $1$. The procedure that Alice used to make her measurements certain involved some fiddly business with a third qubit, and now what is entangled is that third qubit and Bob's.

---

*The operations of the form $U\otimes \mathbf{1}$ really *can't* work because they change the state to $|\psi'\rangle = U|0\rangle|1\rangle + U|1\rangle|0\rangle \neq |01\rangle$. Ultimately, there is nothing Alice can do to influence Bob's reduced density matrix other than measuring her qubit.

Comment: Why should U be unitary? Measurements are not unitary and are part of QM and the world. So an operation on A can act similarly and reduce al0>+bl1> to l0>. Here is a concrete example: Let l0> of  Alice photon has frequency  f1 and l1> has frequency f2. The photon is directed in a box where f1 is allowed but f2 is not. I think the photon's wavefunction will collapse to just l0> (f1) without affecting the box and changing its state. If the photon is entangled its state must have been projected on state 0 and the state of Bob's photon should be changed instantaneously in accordance.

Comment: @Mercury quantum time evolution is unitary. The only non-unitary processes are measurements, which collapse the state so won't do what you want. We only actually need to require reversible here anyway.

Comment: But in the example above there is in fact a measurement on the photon which forces it in state with f1. What would a photon do if there is a box where f2 can not exist? It is not possible that is does not enter the box. At the moment of entering the photon is still entangled and then it must be projected from the measurement of the box on f1. What would not be as I describe?

Comment: Your concrete example doesn't work like you describe. You can't just transfer photons between resonant cavities like that. What you're doing is taking two resonant cavities, one of which is empty and the other in a superposition of two excited states and coupling them somehow. This is very similar to the method I suggested (that doesn't work) - you introduce a new qubit somehow and simply transfer the entanglement. (Your exact proposed suggestion also sounds like it doesn't conserve energy so I think there's physical problems with implementing it too.)

Comment: I understand your example with the ancilla which turns out to be entangled with Bobs photon replacing Alices photon entanglement. But in your case it comes in contact with Alices photon throught the operator U. In my example the ancilla is the box. But the trick is that there is no interaction between them at the moment when A photon is projected to f1, even a little after until the photon reaches the back wall of the box. How can it transfer a qubit to the box.

Comment: As it concerns Energy conservation I can not understand where it is broken? Can you elaborate on this. Thank you.